# android rtsp over 3g using external IP

Tags: android, rtsp, 3g

I'm developing an app for android for my internship project which is stream a H264 DVR camera to Android as the client.Whenever I use Wifi only I can connect to the DVR using the internal IP, 192.xxx.xxx.xxx with logcat saying

```
04-04 14:30:14.680 1629-1629/? V/DefaultOmaSettingHelper: setSettingHeader: with uri=rtsp://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?
04-04 14:30:14.682 827-1630/? V/SettingsProvider: call(system:MTK-RTSP-CACHE-SIZE) for 0
04-04 14:30:14.682 827-1630/? D/SettingsProvider: lookupValue table system cache contains Key MTK-RTSP-CACHE-SIZE , value = Bundle[{value=null}]
04-04 14:30:14.682 827-1674/? V/SettingsProvider: call(system:mtk_rtsp_min_udp_port) for 0
04-04 14:30:14.682 827-1674/? D/SettingsProvider: lookupValue table system cache contains Key mtk_rtsp_min_udp_port , value = Bundle[{value=1024}]
04-04 14:30:14.682 827-1699/? V/SettingsProvider: call(system:mtk_rtsp_max_udp_port) for 0
04-04 14:30:14.683 827-1699/? D/SettingsProvider: lookupValue table system cache contains Key mtk_rtsp_max_udp_port , value = Bundle[{value=65535}]
04-04 14:30:14.683 827-870/? V/SettingsProvider: call(system:mtk_rtsp_proxy_enabled) for 0
04-04 14:30:14.683 827-870/? D/SettingsProvider: lookupValue table system cache contains Key mtk_rtsp_proxy_enabled , value = Bundle[{value=null}]
04-04 14:30:14.684 1629-1629/? V/DefaultOmaSettingHelper: setOmaSettingHeader: params:minUdpPort=1024minUdpPort=1024maxUdpPort=65535rtspProxyEnable=0rtspProxyHost=nullrtspProxyPort=-1httpProxyEnable=0httpProxyHost=nullhttpProxyPort=-1httpBufferSize=10rtspBufferSize=4
04-04 14:30:14.686 277-277/? I/MediaPlayerService: [setDataSource] setDataSource(rtsp://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?)
04-04 14:30:14.689 277-277/? D/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkDcf ----> path [rtsp://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?]
04-04 14:30:14.689 277-277/? V/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkExistence ----> [rtsp://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?]
04-04 14:30:14.690 277-277/? I/NuPlayer: Is RTSP Streaming
04-04 14:30:14.690 277-277/? D/RTSPSource: init+, RTSP uri headers from AP:
04-04 14:30:14.690 277-277/? D/RTSPSource:      Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46
04-04 14:30:14.690 277-277/? D/RTSPSource:      MAX-UDP-PORT: 65535
04-04 14:30:14.691 277-277/? D/RTSPSource:      MIN-UDP-PORT: 1024
04-04 14:30:14.691 277-277/? D/RTSPSource:      MTK-HTTP-CACHE-SIZE: 10
04-04 14:30:14.691 277-277/? D/RTSPSource:      MTK-RTSP-CACHE-SIZE: 4
04-04 14:30:14.691 277-277/? D/RTSPSource: removeSpecificHeaders MTK-RTSP-CACHE-SIZE
04-04 14:30:14.691 277-277/? D/RTSPSource: special headers: MTK-RTSP-CACHE-SIZE = 4
04-04 14:30:14.691 277-277/? I/RTSPSource: RTSP cache size = 4000000us
04-04 14:30:14.692 277-277/? I/MediaPlayerService: [setDataSource] setDataSource(rtsp://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?) done
04-04 14:30:14.697 277-2204/? D/MyHandler: RTSP Max UDP Port: 65535
04-04 14:30:14.697 277-2204/? D/MyHandler: RTSP Min UDP Port: 1024
04-04 14:30:14.705 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: set nodelay return 0
04-04 14:30:14.705 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: connecting 192.168.0.18, 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:554 now
04-04 14:30:14.706 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: connection EINPROGRESS
04-04 14:30:14.741 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
04-04 14:30:14.741 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Content-Type: application/sdp'
04-04 14:30:14.742 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Server: H264DVR 1.0'
04-04 14:30:14.742 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Cseq: 1'
04-04 14:30:14.742 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Content-Base: rtsp://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0./'
04-04 14:30:14.742 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Cache-Control: private'
04-04 14:30:14.742 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'x-Accept-Retransmit: our-retransmit'
04-04 14:30:14.742 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'x-Accept-Dynamic-Rate: 1'
04-04 14:30:14.742 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Content-Length: 356'
04-04 14:30:14.743 277-2209/? I/ASessionDescription: s=RTSP Session
04-04 14:30:14.743 277-2209/? I/MyHandler: base url rtsp://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0./
04-04 14:30:14.754 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
04-04 14:30:14.755 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Server: H264DVR 1.0'
04-04 14:30:14.755 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Cseq: 2'
04-04 14:30:14.755 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Session: 193306800;timeout=60'
04-04 14:30:14.755 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;mode=PLAY;source=192.xxx.xxx.xxx;client_port=46234-46235;server_port=40000-40001;ssrc=0'
04-04 14:30:14.755 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Cache-Control: private'
04-04 14:30:14.755 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'x-Dynamic-Rate: 1'
04-04 14:30:14.759 277-2205/? I/RTSPSource: rtsp s=RTSP Session 
04-04 14:30:14.759 277-2205/? I/RTSPSource: convertMetaDataToMessage OK
04-04 14:30:15.015 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
04-04 14:30:15.015 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Server: H264DVR 1.0'
04-04 14:30:15.015 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Cseq: 3'
04-04 14:30:15.017 277-2215/? I/ACodec: mSupportsPartialFrames 1 err 0 
04-04 14:30:15.018 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Range: npt=now-'
04-04 14:30:15.018 277-2207/? I/ARTSPConnection: line: 'Session: 193306800'
04-04 14:30:15.020 277-2213/? I/NuPlayerDecoder: mSupportsPartialFrames 1
```

HOWEVER,if I use external IP, 60.xxx.xxx.xxx , using either WiFi or 3G i only get logcat

```
04-04 14:24:32.677 31474-31474/? V/DefaultOmaSettingHelper: setSettingHeader: with uri=rtsp://60.xxx.xxx.xxx:2218/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?
04-04 14:24:32.678 827-1089/? V/SettingsProvider: call(system:MTK-RTSP-CACHE-SIZE) for 0
04-04 14:24:32.678 827-1089/? D/SettingsProvider: lookupValue table system cache contains Key MTK-RTSP-CACHE-SIZE , value = Bundle[{value=null}]
04-04 14:24:32.679 827-847/? V/SettingsProvider: call(system:mtk_rtsp_min_udp_port) for 0
04-04 14:24:32.679 827-847/? D/SettingsProvider: lookupValue table system cache contains Key mtk_rtsp_min_udp_port , value = Bundle[{value=1024}]
04-04 14:24:32.679 827-1002/? V/SettingsProvider: call(system:mtk_rtsp_max_udp_port) for 0
04-04 14:24:32.679 827-1002/? D/SettingsProvider: lookupValue table system cache contains Key mtk_rtsp_max_udp_port , value = Bundle[{value=65535}]
04-04 14:24:32.680 827-1674/? V/SettingsProvider: call(system:mtk_rtsp_proxy_enabled) for 0
04-04 14:24:32.680 827-1674/? D/SettingsProvider: lookupValue table system cache contains Key mtk_rtsp_proxy_enabled , value = Bundle[{value=null}]
04-04 14:24:32.681 31474-31474/? V/DefaultOmaSettingHelper: setOmaSettingHeader: params:minUdpPort=1024minUdpPort=1024maxUdpPort=65535rtspProxyEnable=0rtspProxyHost=nullrtspProxyPort=-1httpProxyEnable=0httpProxyHost=nullhttpProxyPort=-1httpBufferSize=10rtspBufferSize=4
04-04 14:24:32.683 277-13212/? I/MediaPlayerService: [setDataSource] setDataSource(rtsp://60.xxx.xxx.xxx:2218/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?)
04-04 14:24:32.683 277-13212/? D/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkDcf ----> path [rtsp://60.xxx.xxx.xxx:2218/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?]
04-04 14:24:32.683 277-13212/? V/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkExistence ----> [rtsp://60.xxx.xxxx.xxx:2218/user=xxx&password=xx&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?]
04-04 14:24:32.684 277-13212/? I/NuPlayer: Is RTSP Streaming
04-04 14:24:32.684 277-13212/? D/RTSPSource: init+, RTSP uri headers from AP:
04-04 14:24:32.684 277-13212/? D/RTSPSource:        Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46
04-04 14:24:32.684 277-13212/? D/RTSPSource:        MAX-UDP-PORT: 65535
04-04 14:24:32.684 277-13212/? D/RTSPSource:        MIN-UDP-PORT: 1024
04-04 14:24:32.684 277-13212/? D/RTSPSource:        MTK-HTTP-CACHE-SIZE: 10
04-04 14:24:32.684 277-13212/? D/RTSPSource:        MTK-RTSP-CACHE-SIZE: 4
04-04 14:24:32.684 277-13212/? D/RTSPSource: removeSpecificHeaders MTK-RTSP-CACHE-SIZE
04-04 14:24:32.684 277-13212/? D/RTSPSource: special headers: MTK-RTSP-CACHE-SIZE = 4
04-04 14:24:32.684 277-13212/? I/RTSPSource: RTSP cache size = 4000000us
04-04 14:24:32.686 277-13212/? I/MediaPlayerService: [setDataSource] setDataSource(rtsp://60.xxx.xxx.xxx:2218/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?) done
04-04 14:24:32.692 277-32374/? D/MyHandler: RTSP Max UDP Port: 65535
04-04 14:24:32.692 277-32374/? D/MyHandler: RTSP Min UDP Port: 1024
04-04 14:24:32.696 277-32377/? I/ARTSPConnection: set nodelay return 0
04-04 14:24:32.696 277-32377/? I/ARTSPConnection: connecting    60.xxx.xxx.xxx, 60.xxx.xxx.xxx:2218 now
04-04 14:24:32.697 277-32377/? I/ARTSPConnection: connection EINPROGRESS
```

So can anyone tell me what is my problem?Do I need to use socket,packet,input/outputstream,bufferedreader/writer or anything?If so, please give me some examples so I can learn how to use them

P.S Tested on a real device(Elephone P8000 Android 5.0)

**EDIT**

Source Code for the streaming activity

```
public class liveActivity extends Activity{

final static String USERNAME = "xxx";
final static String PASSWORD = "xxx";
public static String domainName = "60.xxx.xxx.xxx";
public static int PORT = 2018;
public static final String URL = "rtsp://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/user=" + USERNAME + "&password=" + PASSWORD + "&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?";
public static final String URL2 = "rtsp://" + domainName + ":" + PORT + "/user=" + USERNAME + "&password=" + PASSWORD + "&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?";

private MediaPlayer mPlayer1;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer2;
SurfaceHolder.Callback mCallback1;
SurfaceHolder.Callback mCallback2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live);

    try{

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();

    mCallback1 = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

            try {

                mPlayer1.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                Map<String, String> headers = getRtspHeaders();
                Uri source = Uri.parse(URL2);
                mPlayer1.setDataSource(context, source, headers);
                mPlayer1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mPlayer1.start();
                    }
                });
                mPlayer1.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

            mPlayer1.release();
        }
    };

    final SurfaceView surfaceView1 =
            (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    // Configure the Surface View.
    surfaceView1.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    // Configure the Surface Holder and register the callback.
    SurfaceHolder holder1 = surfaceView1.getHolder();
    holder1.addCallback(mCallback1);
    holder1.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    /*final SurfaceView surfaceView2 =
            (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView2);
    // Configure the Surface View.
    surfaceView2.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    // Configure the Surface Holder and register the callback.
    SurfaceHolder holder2 = surfaceView2.getHolder();
    holder2.addCallback(mCallback2);
    holder2.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);*/

}


private Map<String, String> getRtspHeaders() {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String basicAuthValue = getBasicAuthValue(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    headers.put("Authorization", basicAuthValue);
    return headers;
}

private String getBasicAuthValue(String user, String password) {
    String credentials = user + ":" + password;
    int flags = Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP;
    byte[] bytes = credentials.getBytes();
    return "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(bytes, flags);
}

}
```

Note : those "xxx" are for security purposes only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to be sure without more info and seeing the code, but the most likely problem is that your provider is blocking this type of connection across its network - some operators will block 'uplink' streaming traffic, either to preserve bandwidth or because they may think it is a VoIP like service competing with one of their services.

The reason it works on WiFi is that most likely both your Android device and your Camera are on the same network with no firewalls etc between them.

Comment: Thank you for your response Mick,I suspected something like that or similar to NAT-related problem but would like to know if something else could cause it.I have editted my question and added the source code where it all process.It's a simple code but would it make a difference if I used some support class instead?

Comment: I can't see any issue with your code form a quick scan. I's suggest trying to connect another streaming player to your camera via the URL and see if that has issues also - this one if available freely on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rtspplr.app&hl=en

Comment: sadly the only app that works with the DVR I'm working with is MEye,but hell I extracted the apk's code and it was too high level for me to understand.Thanks for the help anyway